# Why is this happening to me with the source in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, source

I problem after problem ...
I spend above and it has happened again, I Pungo an image with what happens to me, with some letters on the screen I get a horizontal grating that prevents me from seeing the letter in comfort and fluency, I passed in the browser firefox and also throughout the system, configuration, applications, etc..

[image]

I hope you can solve the problem as soon as possible, it is a burden and uncomfortable to see the letters as well.

A Saud and thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase your title like: "Broken fonts in firefox". I've tested this with my 11.10 (I don't know what you mean by _source_) and everything was fine.

Comment: I can make it look like your problem if I change my HDMI cable to a VGA cable using the same TV right now. Am using an Nvidia card but am guessing this is not an Ubuntu issue as more of a "What cable am using and output monitor".

Comment: Can you add, resolution you are using, video card, video cable conencted to the pc.

Comment: The computer has nothing to do, is in perfect order with other operating systems, which are many.
It has to do with ubuntu, some configuration, any more codec installed that should not have installed ...
Greetings.

Comment: Fixed, you must uninstall the following package Synaptic Package Manager:
ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Thank you, greetings.

Comment: please post your answer in the answers section otherwise the system will regard your question as still unsolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you stated in your comment above:

Fixed, you must uninstall the following package via the Synaptic Package Manager: `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

The command line method is as follows:

`sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer`